# How to construct integer value from vector<bool> of values in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<bool> bitvec{true, false, true, false, true};
    std::string str;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < bitvec.size(); ++i)
    {   
        // str += bitvec[i];
        std::vector<bool>::reference ref = bitvec[i];
        // str += ref;
        std::cout << "bitvec[" << i << "] : " << bitvec[i] << '\n';
        std::cout << "str[" << i << "] : " << str[i] << '\n';
    }   
    std::cout << "str : " << str << '\n';
}
```

How we can construct an integer value from the std::vector of bool values. I thought to convert it to a std::string and then to integer from std::vector of bool values, but converting it to string from std::vector of bool values is failing. I know that both std::vector of bool and std::string elements are not the same type. So need help for the same.

Comment: `std::vector<bool>` isn't such a good idea, rather use a `std::bitset`.

Comment: Can you give an example of the input vector and the int value expected as output.

Comment: What kind of conversion are you looking for? Do you want to interpret the booleans as bits? If so, then which position represents the most significant bit, first or last.

Comment: I want individual bits to be represented as binary digits and then it be converted to integer(decimal) value.

Comment: Which position represents the most significant bit?

Comment: bitvec[0] represents the most significant bit.

Comment: Is the length of bitvector known at compile time or is it dynamic?

Comment: size of bitvector is known during run time, so only used std::vector<bool>.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is probably what you are looking for:

```
auto value = std::accumulate(
    bitvec.begin(), bitvec.end(), 0ull,
    [](auto acc, auto bit) { return (acc << 1) | bit; });
```

`std::accumulate` is present in the `<numeric>` header

Explanation: We iterate over the elements in the vector and keep accumulating the partial result in `acc`. When a new bit has to be added to `acc`, we make space for the new bit by left shifting `acc` and then add the bit by or'ing it with acc.